# How to create About Dialog or About Page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am just finishing my latest app but I am straggling with the About page implementation.

How should I create About Dialog  or About Page in Windows Phone?

I do not want to use just a plain page with text, because it doesn't look professional.  Is there a standard way of doing this?  An About page/dialog provided within the framework, for example?

Comment: I'd say take a survey of about pages from apps you think are well designed and use them as your guide.

Comment: Copy the Windows Phone About page in settings. It looks great, if you're already using similar styling.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. The best would be if you could download a few of the popular free apps to see how exactly have they implemented it, to get a few ideas.

I prefer to go in one of the following 2 directions:

1. Custom styled page, that includes icons, developer details, some legal details (which controls did you use, under which licenses etc.) You can even use a pivot page, and then split the details about you, and legal details (and any other details) to multiple pivot items.
2. Use a popup [from Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). Scroll down for a sample of how it looks.